# Why does the norm defined on function spaces work?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I find it amusing why the infimum norm or supremum norm defined on function spaces work actually? It's difficult for me to reach to an intuition where I would see the infimum or supremum as a natural way to represent distance between two functions. Is there any intuition which can motivate the norms defined on function spaces ? How do we make sure that two functions having the same infimum or supremum don't deviate too much from each other and that the function which is a limit under such a norm satisfies the properties the functions in the sequence have ?

[What is the norm measuring in function spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19866/what-is-the-norm-measuring-in-function-spaces)

I went thorugh the above question but could not find an intuitive way to address the last question in the first paragraph of my post .

Disclaimer : I am not  a pure maths student , please pardon my immaturities . I was just trying to find an intuition here.

Comment: I think you are misreading the definition of the $L^\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misconception: We do *not* consider the difference of the suprema as the distance of two functions. Instead the distance of two functions is
$$d(f,g) = || f - g|| = \sup\{|f(x) - g(x)| : x \in \Omega\},$$
i.e. you take the supremum of the difference. If that is small, it means that the two functions $f$ and $g$ differ by at most $d(f,g)$ at any point $x \in \Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other intuitiveways to define norms in function spaces ?

Comment: $p$-norms with $p<\infty$ translate really naturally from finite to infinite-dimenions. E.g., $\|f\|_p = \sqrt[p]{\int_\Omega |f(x)|^pdx}$. Compare this to the finite-dimensional case $\|v\|_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^p}$. If the elements of $v$ are pointwise evaluations of a function $f$ on a suitable set of $n$ points in $\Omega$, then the finite-dim norm can converge to the finite-dim norm of the function $f$ with proper scaling.